# Initialize collection of objects in Java Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, initialization

I want to create some kind of Enumeration Manager - that class should contain collection of all objects from database.
**Question:** How to initialize that collection? This is my starting point:

```
@Component(EnumerationManager.SPORT_ENUM)
@Scope(value = "singleton")

public class SportEnumManager implements EnumerationManager<SportEnum, Long>{

@Autowired
SportEnumDAO gsportEnumDAO;

private Map<Long, SportEnum> objects;
private boolean initialized = false;

@Override
@Transactional
public SportEnum findById(Long id) {
    return objects.get(id);
}   

@PostInitialize
public void init(){
    objects = new HashMap<>();
    List<GenderEnum> list = genderEnumDAO.getAll();
    for (GenderEnum ge : list) {
        objects.put(ge.getId(), ge);
    }
    }

}
```

Problem is that sessionFactory is not available in @PostContructor "time".

Here are others config stuff

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd ">

  <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c.*" /> 

  <tx:annotation-driven/>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />


 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxyyy" />
    <property name="username" value="XXX" />
    <property name="password" value="YYY" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>

                <value>...</value>                                

            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>       
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>        
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>                       
      </props>    
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `@postconstruct` can only ensure that, method is called after the bean is created but it doesn't mean that all the other BeanPostProcessor already did their respective jobs. so in short it doesn't ensure the container is ready for everything here and that's why session is not available.Already jira is added for this http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5966.

You can try this by registering `ContextRefreshedEvent` event in `ApplicationListener`.

Comment: So the best way for my goal (initializing some collection) is to use ContextRefreshedEvent?

Comment: @patak Yes, I think so, at least until it won't get resolved. Take look of Patch written by zvizvi (on jira https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5966), I have never tried for this but I had a POC on this. It seems work.

Comment: thanks a lot. I solved my issue with `ContextRefreshedEvent` event in `ApplicationListener`.

Comment: @patak, congratulations, you can update answer with the code you have done so that others (who may need help in future) will get help from that :)